# Copy a html.Response, then get the string

Tags: go

I have made an `Url` type that should contain the response body.

```
type Url struct {
    Address string
    Refresh string
    Watch   string
    Found   bool
    Body    bytes.Buffer // bytes.Buffer needs no initialization
}
```

An Url object is created with the right `Address`, and then I do

```
resp, err := http.Get(url.Address)
```

Now I would like to do something like the following, but I cannot get out of it:

```
io.Copy(url.Body, b) // Copy that to the Url buffer
```

As for now, the `Url.Body` field can be modified to another type if needed.

Afterwards, I want to get the string from that Buffer/Writer/whatever, but I assume this will be easy as soon as I will manage the former copy.

Regards,
Le Barde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) which returns `[]byte`:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url.Address)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
url.Body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!